# Is this behavior of find -cmin normal?

Tags: linux, permissions, find, metadata

I have two files

```
-rw-rw----  1 1000 1000   5 Sep 28 01:25 file1
-rw-rw----  1 1000 1000  13 Sep 28 01:25 file2
```

After `echo "asdfg" >> file1` (file1 content was modified)

```
-rw-rw----  1 1000 1000  11 Sep 28 01:25 file1
-rw-rw----  1 1000 1000  13 Sep 28 01:25 file2
```

And `chmod 770 file2` (file2 meta was changed)

```
-rw-rw----  1 1000 1000  11 Sep 28 01:25 file1
-rwxrwx---  1 1000 1000  13 Sep 28 01:25 file2
```

Run `find . -mmin -5` within 5mins, result as expected because only file1 data was modified

```
./file1
```

Run `find . -cmin -5` then I have this

```
./file2
./file1
```

file2 meta was changed to 770 but file1 still 660. Question: why `-cmin` also list file1? Is this a normal behavior? Because all I want `-cmin` to do is list one with permissions changed only. If it is normal, anybody could tell me on how to achieve my original intention please?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-mtime-atime-and-ctime

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: The `ctime` is updated whenever any of the attributes of a file is changed. Since writing to the file updates the `mtime` attribute, that also causes `ctime` to change.

Comment: Use `ls -lc` to see the `ctime` of the files, there's no need to use `find`.

Comment: @Barmar I want to use `find` to reach necessary targets in huge directories & subs without listing every single file

Comment: I just meant to use `ls` to see the effect that writing to a file has on the `ctime`.

Comment: Ah, maybe I did not make it clear. I use `find` to do some non user interactive things, needless to see the output until I have to (occasionally)